# Why are arrays not passed by reference when using Multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Basically, in the example below I want to fill up a five element list with the position of each element in the list. I am doing this using multiprocessing. So I expect that even though each iteration of filling in the list may not occur following the more intuitive order (from first element to last element), in the end the list will nonetheless be filled correctly. This relies on the assumption that arr is passed by reference, and thus can in fact be altered each time function f is called. However, arr is never altered, and when we print it out, it is still what it was initialized to, namely [0]*5 = [0,0,0,0,0].

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

arr = [0]*5
cases = [0,1,2,3,4]

def f(arr, position):
    arr[position] = position


num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(f)(arr, position) for position in cases) 

print arr
```

When we don't use multiprocessing, we get expected results:

```
def f(arr, position):
arr[position] = position

arr = [0]*5

for i, el in enumerate(arr):
    f(arr, i)

print arr
```

Why does this happen, ie, why aren't lists passed by reference when using multiprocessing?

Comment: Take a look at queue's https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: You have to use the ``Queue`` or ``queue`` (py3+) modules if you want to manipulate variables in another thread.  Pipes can also be used, but I haven't seen too much code take this route.

Comment: A simply answer to your question - *why aren't lists passed by reference when using multiprocessing* - would be - because they are different processes , and memory is not shared between different processes.

Comment: You might want to read this about Python's pass-by-reference and pass-by-value: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2010-December/080505.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is populate the list, then you should try using `multiprocessing.Pool.map`. The only problem with `map` is that it waits for all tasks to finish before returning. So you may wish to explore the `imap` alternatives. It may be that each task takes a substantially different amount of time. In that case look at `imap_unordered` (of which I've also included an example of).

eg.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing

def f(n):
    return n * 2

def g(args):
    id_, n = args
    return id_, -n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cases = range(5)
    # Pool automatically uses the same number of subprocesses as cpu_count
    with closing(Pool()) as pool:
        arr = pool.map(f, cases)
    print(arr) # prints [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]

    arr = [None] * len(cases)
    with closing(Pool()) as pool:
        for idx, result in pool.imap_unordered(g, enumerate(cases)):
            arr[idx] = result
    print(arr) # prints [0, -1, -2, -3, -4]
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the error:
line 13, in <module>
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:

AttributeError:  __exit__

Comment: I get the same error when I try it on the actual function I need this for, which does something a little more complicated but just returns a number  so in the end your solution should work though. But no idea why I get this error, I just copied and pasted your code and got the error.

Comment: You are running python 2, which I didn't notice. You can't use the with statement with a Pool in python 2.

Comment: Have made the code python 2 compatible. `closing` just wraps the pool in an object, which can be used in a with statement.